# INVALID dictionary 0 ). Why I Am Getting this Error?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios, nsdictionary

I am getting this message only the first time that I touch over the top search bar of a table.

```
INVALID dictionary 0 
)
INVALID dictionary 0 
)
```

All still working after the warning but I prefer do not see it. Someone knows why I am getting this message?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like not an iOS 4.2 bug. Something else. Sometimes I get this problem with 4.2. I'm not sure, but I noticed this this error sometimes occurs when I use no en_US localizations, for example - Spanish .

Comment: Yes berec, your are right. Fortunately, now with 4.3.2 iOS version the problem is solved. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with iOS 4.2. I am not getting this problem anymore. I think it was a bug of the 4.0. version.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue running iOS 4.3.6 calling `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]`, which resulted in the following output:

```
   INVALID dictionary 0
   )
   WARNING: Input manager failed to load static dictionary for: nl_NL
   INVALID dictionary 0
   )
```

The `WARNING` reminded me that I had previously enabled a Dutch keyboard for testing purposes. Removing that keyboard via iOS Settings got rid of the warning for me.

This is obviously not an valid solution if your app supports multiple languages, but for my purposes this was acceptable. Hope that helps someone.